# MS Access Code issue for Reminders

Tags: ms-access, vba, reminders

I'm trying to setup reminders based on tasks added from a Table called "Tasks" Here is the code I'm using but something isn't right as it keeps giving me issues with the following line:

```vb
intStore = DCount("[TaskName]", "[Status]", "[DueDate] <=Now() AND [Complete] =0")
```

When the code runs I get the error:

> Microsoft Access database engine cannot find the input table or query
>   for 'Status' Make sure it exists and is spelled correctly.

In my table I have fields for **Task Name**, **Status**, and **Due Date** so I'm not exactly sure why this is coming up.

Below is the entire line of code:

```vb
Private Sub Form_Load()

    'On Load of the switchboard check Jobs table for any uncompleted jobs

    Dim intStore As Integer

    intStore = DCount("[Priority]", "[Tasks]", "[DueDate] <=Now() AND [PercentComplete] <=0")

    If intStore = 0 Then
        Exit Sub
    Else        
        If MsgBox("There are " & intStore & " uncompleted jobs" & _
        vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Would you like to see these now?", _
        vbYesNo, "You Have Uncomplete Jobs...") = vbYes Then
            DoCmd.Minimize
            DoCmd.OpenForm "Tasks", acNormal
        Else
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Do you have a table called Status?

Comment: No, do I need to have a table for each? I was hoping I could use the headers under the table for Tasks since the form I'm using adds all the information there.

Comment: `DCount`'s 3 arguments are `field`, `table/query`, `expression`. You've put "Status" in the part where it's expecting a `table/query`, and since you don't have a table/query with that name, it's triggering the error. I think if you just replace "Status" with "Tasks" it will probably work.. let us know if doesn't and what error message you get.

Comment: Okay so using the following code   `intStore = DCount("[TaskName]", "[Tasks]", "[DueDate] <=Now() AND [Complete] =0")`    I get the following error: "the expression you entered as a query parameter produced this error: '[TaskName]'

Comment: Are `TaskName`, `DueDate` and `Complete` all fields in the `Tasks` table and spelled as shown? You mentioned in your original question that you have a field called `Task Name`.. suggesting it has a space. If it has a space you need to to write it as `DCount("[Task Name]", ...`

Comment: I added the spaces but having a strange issue. Task Name works but Due Date and Percent Complete say "The expression you entered as a query parameter produced this error "[Due Date]" and this happens for both. if I remove the space they go through and the pop up comes up (progress!!) but it opens Form1 but the other form that's supposed to come up and show me the uncompleted tasks doesn't appear.

Comment: You have to refer to the field names *exactly* how you set them up for the table. I'm not too sure on the issue with the form not opening.. possibly need to reselect the form you want to minimize before minimizing it. Take a look at `DoCmd.SelectObject` https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff835629

Comment: Okay so quick update. I've got the pop up working, it's showing the proper number of items uncompleted etc... the problem I'm having now is, while it opens the main form (Form1) and it opens a form I created called "Tasks" which displays the task records. It doesn't exactly show only the uncompleted tasks like I'm hoping for. Is there something I need to do to the "Tasks" form I created so it shows only those items that are uncompleted and not all the records? I'll update the code above

Comment: You'll need to filter the Tasks form I would think.. perhaps start a new question at this stage as I think this is moving away from the original coding problem you raised.

Comment: I will do that Matt. Thanks so much for all your help!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only perform a DCount on one field (primary key is best if you are just doing a general count on the table). You have entered "[Status]" where Access is expecting a table or query name to be used as the source of the [TaskName] field.

See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa211471(v=office.11).aspx) for more information.

Judging by your other code example I expect that your code needs to be:

```
intStore = DCount("[TaskName]", "[Tasks]", "[DueDate] <=Now() AND [Complete] =0")
```